# css for setting background to transparent for select elements in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, background-color

I have code like this

```
<div>
  <select>
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
     <option>Option 4</option>
  <select>
</div>
```

The div has a background image which should be visible through the select box. The issue I have is with IE7 where I am not able to set the background color of the select element to transparent.

EDIT: the image is only the down pointing arrow. The text is real text.

I have used this CSS but it doesn't work

```
background-color:transparent
```

Here is a screenshot to help better understand

[image]

Comment: We can't really help without seeing some css, but try setting `display: inline;` on the text, that should remove the background

Comment: Is your css rule on the select-element, or the option-element?

Comment: background-color:transparent is on the select, but I have also tried on the option

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
.transparent {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

IE7 is not really your best friend when it comes to web development. There are a lot of things that will not work.

There are however some good javascript plugins that you can use to override the default styling.

[I personally use this one at work.](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) when I need to support IE7 with custom dropdowns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have tried your css code and it does remove the white background, however it also makes the text dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an image to display text, try setting the font-size to 0px:

> font-size:0px

Answer (score 0):

Raised from the dead but maybe helpful for others coming across this.

Use this meta, which has to be the first thing under the head

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

This should work.